# python mysql.connector write failure on connection disconnection stalls for 30 seconds

Tags: python, mysql, mysql-connector, mysql-connector-python, database-connection

I use python module `mysql.connector` for connecting to an `AWS RDS` instance.

Now, as we know, if we do not send a request to SQL server for a while, the connection disconnects.

To handle this, I reconnect to SQL in case a read/write **request fails**.

Now my problem with the **"request fails"**, it takes significant to fail. And only then can I reconnect, and retry my request. (I have pointed this out as a comment in code snippet).

For a real-time application such as mine, this is a problem. How could I solve this? Is it possible to find out if the disconnection has already happened so that I can try a new connection without having to wait on a read/write request?

Here is how I handle it in my code right now:

```
def fetchFromDB(self, vid_id):
    fetch_query = "SELECT * FROM <db>"
    success = False
    attempts = 0
    output = []
    while not success and attempts < self.MAX_CONN_ATTEMPTS:
        try:
            if self.cnx == None:
                self._connectDB_()

            if self.cnx:
                cursor = self.cnx.cursor() # MY PROBLEM: This step takes too long to fail in case the connection has expired.
                cursor.execute(fetch_query)

                output = []
                for entry in cursor:
                    output.append(entry)
                cursor.close()
                success = True
            attempts = attempts + 1
        except Exception as ex:
            logging.warning("Error")
            if self.cnx != None:
                try:
                    self.cnx.close()
                except Exception as ex:
                    pass
                finally:
                    self.cnx = None
    return output
```

In my application I cannot tolerate a delay of more than 1 second while reading from mysql.
While configuring mysql, I'm doing just the following settings:

```
SQL.user = '<username>'
SQL.password = '<password>'
SQL.host = '<AWS RDS HOST>'
SQL.port = 3306
SQL.raise_on_warnings = True
SQL.use_pure = True 
SQL.database = <database-name>
```

Answer (score 0):

There are some contrivances like generating an ALARM signal or similar if a function call takes too long. Those can be tricky with database connections or not work at all. There are [other SO questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1507091/python-mysqldb-query-timeout) that go there.

One approach would be to set the [connection_timeout](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-connectargs.html) to a known value when you create the connection making sure it's shorter than the [server side timeout](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_wait_timeout). Then if you track the age of the connection yourself you can preemptively reconnect before it gets too old and clean up the previous connection.

Alternatively you could occasionally execute a no-op query like `select now();` to keep the connection open. You would still want to recycle the connection every so often.

But if there are long enough periods between queries (where they might expire) why not open a new connection for each query?

Comment: The time between queries is not fixed. At times we have many queries in a short time. And at times, there can be a gap as long as 5 minute. I'm considering the no-op query approach you mentioned. Thanks!